# Jasmine can't read a valid json file

Tags: javascript, json, jasmine

I have this JSON file :

```
{
"Address": [{
    "street": "rue de la paix",
    "zipcode": "3049"
}, {
    "street": "champs de mars",
    "zipcode": "2303"
}]
}
```

Which is valid. I'm trying to read that file in one of my Jasmine specifications. When I ajax it I get my file contents and everything works fine.

But, when I launch my test `maven` in console log I get error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :** in the second line, just after the "Address".
[image]

And if I remove the ":" the error disappears but I can no longer read the file (which is very understandable).

Code of maven goal is defined as follows:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <specRunnerTemplate>REQUIRE_JS</specRunnerTemplate>
      <preloadSources>
         <source>jsonResources/testjson.json</source>
      </preloadSources>
      <specIncludes>
         <include>**/*.spec.js</include>
      </specIncludes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Had anyone had a similar problem ?

Comment: Can you share Jasmine code that attempts to read the file and fails?

Comment: could you provide the code where it is used?

Comment: @KirillSlatin, @raszpi

`beforeEach(function()
    {
     
     /* Reading file contents */
     $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      dataType : 'json',
      async : false,
      url : 'http://localhost:8234/src/jsonResources/testjson.json',
      success : function(data){
       contents = data["Address"];
      }
     });
    });`

Comment: The ajax request works fine if json file is well formatted (with the ":").
But, that error remains which cause the failure of the maven plugin goal

Comment: @Hamzaaton, so obviously it is not the code that fails... I am still unsure where the error is. On the screenshot you posted there are `46 specs, 0 failures`

Comment: @KirillSlatin exactly ! The code works fine. I could've just leave it like that. But the Uncaught SyntaxError fails my maven goal. 

That's what I don't understand. : (

Comment: So I suppose it is something to do with the mavel plugin. There must be something wrong with the return value or notification function... Please post in the question the code of the goal that fails

Comment: @KirillSlatin, here : 
`<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <specRunnerTemplate>REQUIRE_JS</specRunnerTemplate>
     <preloadSources>
      <source>jsonResources/testjson.json</source>
     </preloadSources>
     <specIncludes>
      <include>**/*.spec.js</include>
     </specIncludes>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>`

Comment: I am not familiar with maven but I guess the problem is in referencing `testjson.json` as source. That's what I thought was the issue, json file treated as wrong type...

Comment: I guess so, yes. 
When I removed the json file from the <PreloadSources> tag, the error is no longer shown.

Comment: @Hamzaaton, I've modified your question for benefit of future readers and added conclusion of discussion as answer. Please mark it as accepted if you don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `maven` doesn't like `json` file referenced as source. Because it is parsed as javascript code